# Given one restrict pointer based on another, should they never alias?

Tags: c, c99, restrict-qualifier

As far as I understand the formal definition of "restrict" in [section 6.7.3.1 of the C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3.1),
in the function below, pointer `y` is based on a `restrict` pointer `x`; hence, the compiler will assume that accesses `*x` and `*y` might alias:

```c
void assign1(int *pA, long N) {
  int *restrict x = pA;
  { 
    int *y = x + N;
    *x = *y;
  }
}
```

However, what if `y` itself is declared `restrict`: can the compiler assume that `*x` and `*y` will never alias?

```c
void assign2(int *pA, long N) {
  int *restrict x = pA;
  { 
    int *restrict y = x + N;
    *x = *y;
  }     
}
```

Comment: You might prefer the [HTML version of the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) or, specifically [C11p6.7.3.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3.1).

Comment: @pmg Thanks, I updated the question with the new link.

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting Jeroen Dobbelaere](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2020-February/139176.html), an LLVM developer working on a "restrict" implementation:

This is defined in  [6.7.3.1 paragraph 4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3.1p4):

> ... Every other lvalue used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P ...

For  `assign1`:

- `x` is a restrict pointer and is assumed to point to its own set of objects
- `y` is a normal pointer, based on `x`
- all access to the set of objects pointed by `x` are done through a pointer based on `x`

for `assign2`:

- `x` is a restrict pointer and is assumed to point to its own set of objects
- `y` is also a restrict pointer, based on `x`, but it is assumed to point to its own set of objects for the scope of `y`
- because of that, `*x` and `*y` must never overlap, as all accesses to the objects of `y` must be done based on a pointer derived from `y`

As such, a N=0 will trigger undefined behavior in `assign2`

Doing the assignment to `*x` outside the inner block, makes the code valid again:

```c
void assign3(int *pA, long N) {
  int *restrict x = pA;
  int tmp;
  {
    int *restrict y = x + N;
    tmp = *y;
  }
  *x = tmp; // may alias with *y
}
```